# My if statements are not working

Tags: android, android-webview

Here is my `MainActivity` I used `WebView` in Android Studio but JavaScript is not running.

It just simply loads the webpage but the if statements are not working.

```
package com.techshala.ramyakmehra.flashsalehelper;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wv;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
            ;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            ;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview));
        wv.setFocusable(true);
        wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }
        wv.loadUrl("https://flipkart.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView paramWebView, String paramString) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }

        onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
        {
            onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
            if (paramString.toLowerCase().equals("https://www.flipkart.com/account/login?ret=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2Faccount")) {
            }
            onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
            if (paramString.toLowerCase().equals("https://www.flipkart.com/account/")) {
                wv.loadUrl("https://www.flipkart.com/operon-b57d-dew-bp-monitor/p/itmex9bqpzh4hdsn?pid=BPMEX9BQGRZHWXYT&lid=LSTBPMEX9BQGRZHWXYTWOV79S&marketplace=FLIPKART&srno=b_1_1&otracker=hp_omu_Deals%20of%20the%20Day_1_From%20%E2%82%B9%20749_5F6E9K1E29R8_0&fm=neo/merchandising&iid=5b332980-eab1-4e62-9cff-6946b49e71e4.BPMEX9BQGRZHWXYT.SEARCH&ppt=Store%20Browse&ppn=Search%20Page&ssid=kz8qhsw55s0000001524827753408");
            }onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
            if (paramString.toLowerCase().contains("/p/")) {
                wv.loadUrl("javascript: if ((document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2MWPVK RpigiU') .length > 0) || (document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _2Npkh4 _2kuvG8 _7UHT_c') .length > 0)) { var listId = document.getElementsByClassName(\"niH0FQ _36Fcw_\")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute(\"id\") .split('_')[1]; var hiddenEids = document.createElement(\"input\"); hiddenEids.setAttribute(\"type\", \"hidden\"); hiddenEids.setAttribute(\"name\", \"eids\"); hiddenEids.setAttribute(\"value\", listId); var hiddenOtracker = document.createElement(\"input\"); hiddenOtracker.setAttribute(\"type\", \"hidden\"); hiddenOtracker.setAttribute(\"name\", \"otracker\"); hiddenOtracker.setAttribute(\"value\", \"\"); var hiddenDomain = document.createElement(\"input\"); hiddenDomain.setAttribute(\"type\", \"hidden\"); hiddenDomain.setAttribute(\"name\", \"domain\"); hiddenDomain.setAttribute(\"value\", \"physical\"); var formtag = document.createElement(\"form\"); formtag.setAttribute(\"action\", \"/checkout/init\"); formtag.setAttribute(\"class\", \"buyform\"); formtag.setAttribute(\"method\", \"post\"); formtag.appendChild(hiddenDomain); formtag.appendChild(hiddenOtracker); formtag.appendChild(hiddenEids); document.body.appendChild(formtag); formtag.submit(); clearInterval(time); console.log(\"Script Activated\"); } else { console.log('button not found'); location.reload(); }");

            }onPageFinished(paramWebView, paramString);
            if (paramString.toLowerCase().contains("/checkout/init")) {
                wv.loadUrl("javascript:setInterval(function() {   if ((document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _7UHT_c').length > 0)) {     document.getElementsByClassName('_2AkmmA _7UHT_c')[0].click()   }   if (document.getElementsByClassName('_3pZBmm _3C6tOa _1syowc').length == 0) {     if (document.getElementsByClassName('_3uUUD5').length > 0) {       document.getElementsByClassName('_3uUUD5')[0].click()     }   } }, 100)");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, specifically explain exactly where it's not working and what's your expected outcome.

Comment: the web page simply loads i expect it to automatically redirect to given url in the first if statement and when it finds /p/ in the url it should execute the js in the second if statement
the url has /p/ but the js is not executed i tried to execute the js on the normal browser to see if it is working and it worked

Comment: can you share content of `AndroidMenifest.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not implement `WebChromeClient()` which you have set to `WebView`. You have to define methods anonymously inside `new WebChromeClient()`. Try the code below.

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            // Do your stuff here 
        }
    });
```

Comment: added new webview client

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the webChromeClient

```
wv.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```